# Call functions vs call external program?

Tags: function, unix, sh, disambiguation

Suppose I have a program named `abc` in the search path, and I write a script containing the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
abc() {
    echo Hello
}
$1
```

Invoking this script with a parameter `abc` calls the function. Is there a way to always run the external program instead?

Comment: which external program?

Comment: @SomeshMukherjee: "Suppose I have a program named abc in the search path..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, this seems to do the job:

```
#!/bin/sh
abc() {
    echo Hello
}

# calls whatever the argument contains in a new context
sh -c $1

# I can still call my function
abc
```